# Get session number from namespace USERENV in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle, postgresql-13

While migrating oracle to postgresql I came up with the query:

Oracle:

```
select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID') from dual;
```

What will be the equivalent in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is the [backend PID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.4.2.2.11.1.1.1)

```
select pg_backend_pid();
```